# Can I use the JavaScript facebook SDK for phonegap apps?

Tags: facebook, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I am not sure whether my question is appropriate or not.

I am integrating facebook for the first time and also for the for first my app is multi-platform.

I am integrating facebook in my app for iphone and android.My question are below:

1)If i am doing it with plugin i have to do it separately for both iPhone and Android. Is there any way to integrate Facebook for both in a single effort for eg by using Javascript SDK

2)If yes what it is? and if possible any sample.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use [phonegap-plugin-facebook-connect](https://github.com/davejohnson/phonegap-plugin-facebook-connect/). It works on both iOS and Android and integrates great with iOS6 bulid in Facebook functionality.

The plugin provides a patched version of the Facebook JS API.

Comment: I almost pulled my hair out trying to get **phonegap-plugin-facebook-connect** to work. Never in my life have I been so frustrated with such an awful documentation. Enjoy your **ld: 351 duplicate symbols for architecture armv7** error messages if you this route.

Comment: Did you found a solution for this? I am having a HORRIBLE time trying to setup that plugin

Comment: You have to add more details on what exactly is not working for you if you want help. Besides, the plugin is maintained on GitHub and if you think that something is wrong with it you can open issues there...

Comment: Avoid this plugin, the documentation is outdated and the plugin just doesn't work. I'm stuck for a solution atm.

Comment: this plugin is a nightmare