# Can Facebook JS SDK work with Phonegap / Cordova?

Tags: cordova, facebook-javascript-sdk

I have Senscha 2.0 mobile application which I want to build using latest phonegap (cordova).

I want to add facebook login functionality. I found three options:

1. Use ChildBrowser approach
2. Use InAppBrowser.
3. Use cordova facebook plugin

I decided to go with the second one.

I have problem with domain in FB app settings (Mobile Site URL).

I typed one of my domains there, but when building app using Cordova in xCode, facebook response with an error, because obviously phonegap / cordova doesn't "use" any domain.

When I uploaded my app (without using phonegap) to domain which I typed in Facebook settings, everything works on my iPhone (using as website in Safari).

---

To be more precise.

Facebook JS SDK works when I'm using my application as "mobile web application".

When I build my project using Cordova / Phonegap (it automatically uses InAppBrowser plugin), it stops working.

Will Facebook JS SDK work with Phonegap / Cordova?

Comment: So what is your question?

Comment: It is in topic title:)

Comment: this question was asked before: http://stackoverflow.com/q/15021811/1977815

Comment: Yes, thank you, but that wasn't exactly answer to my question

Comment: Question is "will this work"?

Comment: I'm aware that using this special plugin is the best... However I wanna know if using only javascript facebook sdk will work

Comment: @M.D even i am facing this similar issue, did u get a valid workaround?

Comment: Christophe Coenraets coded a library to achieve openGraph integration only using JavaScript, it may suit your needs: http://coenraets.org/blog/2014/04/facebook-phonegap-cordova-without-plugin/

Comment: You should not use the Javascript approach. It will be a big mess for all people using it, because they have to enter their credentials in the inappbrowser (which they often don't know). So you should really go for option 3).  I know that it is a bit of a hack to include Facebook in your cordova application (I just did a update last week and it took me almost 2 days to get everything back running). But the User-Experience is a lot better!

Comment: As explained in the answer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19652002/facebook-channel-url-for-cordova-app), no, you can't.

Answer (score 0):

It can. Use OpenFB or Facebook Connect Phonegap Plugin.

Reference

OpenFb

- http://coenraets.org/blog/2014/04/facebook-phonegap-cordova-without-plugin/
- https://github.com/ccoenraets/OpenFB

Facebook Connect Phonegap Plugin

- https://github.com/Wizcorp/phonegap-facebook-plugin