# Facebook channel URL for Cordova app

Tags: javascript, facebook, cordova, facebook-javascript-sdk

I am working on a HTML5 mobile app, using cordova 2.6, and I am targetting iOS, Android BlackBerry and Windows Phone.

I am trying to implement Facebook sharing feature using Facebook JavaScript SDK.
I am trying to do it inside Corodova InAppBrowser

My FB.init function is as following:

```
  FB.init({
        appId      : '0000000000',
        channelUrl : './js/libs/fb/channel.html',
        status     : true
      });
```

[image: My Facebook App configuration]

I am having the error :

[image]

Is there anything wrong with my Facebook app configuration, or my FB.init function?

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/javascript/gettingstarted/#channel: _“The channelUrl must be a fully qualified URL”_

Comment: @CBroe what does this mean? I can't put a relative path to a file, right?

Comment: Yepp, that’s what it means.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you wish to use Facebook JS SDK methods inside a phonegap project, you need to use the [Facebook Plugin](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-facebook-plugin)

When you try doing it as a regular website, Facebook blocks you since you didn't provide them the authorized domain. the problem is, your JS code runs locally on each device so you don't have such a domain, and therefor you cannot use the Facebook JS  SDK.

you can avoid the plugin by using some other methods, like a using a childbrowser plugin (look at: [this example](https://github.com/DrewDahlman/phonegapFacebookApp))

good luck

Comment: Thanks for the response, phonegap plugin is not good for me, because I need it to work not only in iOS and Android, but also BB10 and windows phone.     For the second alternative I think I should try it, using InAppBrowser (that replaces child browser plugin, and which is integrated inside latest versions of Cordova / PhoneGap)

Comment: You are right, same principal. its actually pretty easy to implement (i did it in the past). if you found the answer helpful, please consider marking it as answer. thank you