# Why facebook login not working with phonegap on android?

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, cordova, facebook-javascript-sdk

**UPDATE:**

**I almost got it working.
I needed to change `js.src` assignment from `js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";` to: `js.src="https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";`**

**But now when I enter the login screen I have this error:**

> Can't Load URL: The domain of this URL isn't included in the app's
>   domains. To be able to load this url, add all domains and subdomains
>   of your app to the App Domains field in your app settings.

**I did just that but the same error is given.
Any ideas?**

I have an app where I made a facebook login using JavaScript SDK. The code works great on mobile browser and on desktop or laptop browsers, but when I install the app using phonegap I have the next error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: FB is not defined
```

Can anyone please help me with this?

I've read multiple threads on stack about this, but none of them seemed to make some light.

My code is this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  (function(d, s, id) {
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) {
      return;
    }
    js = d.createElement(s);
    js.id = id;
    js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
  }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));

  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
      appId: 'app_id_secret',
      xfbml: true,
      version: 'v2.7'
    });
  };
  // This is called with the results from from FB.getLoginStatus().
  function statusChangeCallback(response) {
    if (response.status === 'connected') {
      // Logged into your app and Facebook.
      getUserData();
    } else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {
      // The person is logged into Facebook, but not your app.
      document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = 'Please log ' +
        'into this app.';
    } else {
      // The person is not logged into Facebook, so we're not sure if
      // they are logged into this app or not.
      document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = 'Please log ' +
        'into Facebook.';
    }
  }

  function checkLoginState() {
    FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
      statusChangeCallback(response);
    });
  }

  $('.fb_login').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    FB.login(function(response) {
      if (response.authResponse) {
        FB.api('/me', {
          fields: 'name, email, first_name, last_name'
        }, function(response) {});
      }
    }, {
      scope: 'email,public_profile',
      return_scopes: true
    });
  });
});
```

I've also found this link [Can Facebook JS SDK work with Phonegap / Cordova?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15288177/can-facebook-js-sdk-work-with-phonegap-cordova) where someone asks almost the same question. There is suggested to use an cordova plugin. Is this a solution? If yes, which one of them is best?

Comment: have you defined FB?

Comment: Looks like it wasn't loading sdk.js. I updated my question. Now I seem to have another problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a plugin called `phonegap.facebook.inappbrowser`, that I think it might help you.

You can find the plugin [here](https://github.com/caiovaccaro/phonegap.facebook.inappbrowser).

First add the plugin script in your file head like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/phonegap.facebook.inappbrowser.js"></script>
```

Then call it using your own custom parameters for app id, redirect url and permissions:

```
// Settings
FacebookInAppBrowser.settings.appId = '123456789';
FacebookInAppBrowser.settings.redirectUrl = 'http://example.com';
FacebookInAppBrowser.settings.permissions = 'email';

// Login(accessToken will be stored trough localStorage in 'accessToken');
FacebookInAppBrowser.login({
    send: function() {
        console.log('login opened');
    },
    success: function(access_token) {
        console.log('done, access token: ' + access_token);
    },
    denied: function() {
        console.log('user denied');
    },
    timeout: function(){
        console.log('a timeout has occurred, probably a bad internet connection');
    },
    complete: function(access_token) {
        console.log('window closed');
        if(access_token) {
            console.log(access_token);
        } else {
            console.log('no access token');
        }
    },
    userInfo: function(userInfo) {
        if(userInfo) {
            console.log(JSON.stringify(userInfo));
        } else {
            console.log('no user info');
        }
    }
});
```

Also, I saw that you want to get the first_name and last_name of the logged in user. The plugin doesn't have those set by default after login. But you can modify a variable in the plugin file called `get_url`. Change it from this:

```
var get_url  = "https://graph.facebook.com/me?fields=email,name,gender&access_token=" + window.localStorage.getItem('facebookAccessToken');
```

To this:

```
var get_url  = "https://graph.facebook.com/me?fields=email,first_name,last_name,name,gender&access_token=" + window.localStorage.getItem('facebookAccessToken');
```